# How to make img element parallax with css?

Tags: html, css, image, styling, parallax

I would like to implement parallax on a bootstrap-based side.
On the top of the page is a header with image. A picture with src-set img to be more concrete.

```
  <body>

  <header>
    <picture>
      <img
        class="main-img"
        sizes="(max-width: 1980px) 100vw, 1980px"
        srcset="
        /img/img-small.jpg   640w,
        /img/img-medium.jpg 1200w,
        /img/img-large.jpg  1980w
      "
      src="/img/img-medium.jpg"
    />
  </picture>
  <div class="header-content">
  ..
  </div>
</header>

<section ...>
```

In every solution i see the backgroud is set over css background: url(..). This would lose the responsive image loading.

Is it possible to implement parallax with this markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a mix of position:sticky and grid , if i understand what you meant by parallax as a staic one.

example from your code :*(height and min-height value are instead real content  tall enough )*

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  display: grid;
  height: 200vh;
  min-height: 1200px;
}

picture img {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

picture,
.header-content {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
}

.header-content {
  margin-top: 56%;
  /*to preserve space according to ratio image */
  border: solid;
  height: 50vh;
  transform: scale(1);
  z-index: 1;
  background: lightgreen;
}

picture img {}
```

```html
<header>
  <picture style="width:100%;">
    <!-- calc(100vw - 1.2em) to mind a scrollbar -->
    <img class="main-img" sizes="(max-width: 1980px) calc(100vw - 1.2em), 1980px" srcset="
        https://dummyimage.com/640x380&text=small   640w,
        https://dummyimage.com/1280x720&text=medium 1280w,
        https://dummyimage.com/1980x1080&text=large   1980w
      " src="https://dummyimage.com/1200x600&text=medium" />
  </picture>
  <div class="header-content">
    .......
  </div>
</header>
```

another approach would be to get the picture ahead the header :

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: grid;
}

picture img {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

picture,
header {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
}

header {
  margin-top: 56%;
}

.header-content {
  height: 100vh;
  background: tomato;
  border: solid;
  transform: scale(1);
  z-index: 1;
}

.header-content:nth-child(odd) {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 3px, gray 6px, gray 7px), repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 3px, gray 6px, gray 7px)
}
main section {height:100vh;background:#bed}
```

```html
<picture style="width:100%;">
  <img class="main-img" sizes="(max-width: 1980px) calc(100vw - 1.2em), 1980px" srcset="
        https://dummyimage.com/640x380&text=small   640w,
        https://dummyimage.com/1280x720&text=medium 1280w,
        https://dummyimage.com/1980x1080&text=large   1980w
      " src="https://dummyimage.com/1200x600&text=medium.jpg" />
</picture>
<header>
  <div class="header-content">
    .......
  </div>
  <div class="header-content">
    .......
  </div>
  <div class="header-content">
    .......
  </div>
  <div class="header-content">
    .......
  </div>
  <div class="header-content">
    .......
  </div>
  <div class="header-content">
    .......
  </div>

</header>
<main> Main
  <section>Section</section>
</main>
```

a parallax with image going slowly up

```css
 

body {
  perspective: 20px;
  perspective-origin: 0%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  display: grid;
}
picture {
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: translateZ(-2px) translatey(-5%);
}
picture img {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

picture,
header {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
}

header {
  margin-top: 56%;
}

.header-content {
  height: 100vh;
  background: tomato;
  border: solid;
  transform: scale(1);
  z-index: 1;
}

.header-content:nth-child(odd) {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 3px, gray 6px, gray 7px), repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 3px, gray 6px, gray 7px)
}
main section {height:100vh;background:#bed}
```

```html
<picture style="width:100%;">
  <img class="main-img" sizes="(max-width: 1980px) calc(100vw - 1.2em), 1980px" srcset="
        https://dummyimage.com/640x380&text=small   640w,
        https://dummyimage.com/1280x720&text=medium 1280w,
        https://dummyimage.com/1980x1080&text=large   1980w
      " src="https://dummyimage.com/1200x600&text=medium.jpg" />
</picture>
<header>
  <div class="header-content">
    .......
  </div>
  <div class="header-content">
    .......
  </div>
  <div class="header-content">
    .......
  </div>
  <div class="header-content">
    .......
  </div>
  <div class="header-content">
    .......
  </div>
  <div class="header-content">
    .......
  </div>

</header>
<main> Main
  <section>Section</section>
</main>
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer. Like the ideas specially the third example with perspective.
Have one issue now. I had a navbar first in body which was fixed (the content was moving under). Now the navbar is going up.
How can i fix that easy way?

Comment: @juri do you have the code to demonstrate somewhere codepen / jsfiddle ?